# Proxying /admin requests to Prisma Studio

Tags: nestjs, http-proxy

I have a nestjs application that uses Postgres+Prisma. My goal is to quickly create an admin panel to manage the database tables. Prisma studio works great for me for this. It runs at localhost:5555, so I created middleware in nestjs that, when requested to /admin, proxies requests to localhost:5555. ( I use [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware))

```
//proxy.middleware.ts
@Injectable()
export class ProxyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private readonly proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://localhost:5555', // Замените на адрес вашего целевого сервера
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { '^/admin': '' },
  });
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
    this.proxy(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

```
//app.module.ts
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(ProxyMiddleware).forRoutes('admin');
  }
}
```

And so, it does redirect requests to Prisma Studio, but an error appears:
[image: Prisma Error]

> POST http://localhost:3333/api 404 (Not Found)

So, it looks like it's trying to fetch studio api by fetching localhost:3333/api, but it doesn't exist there. Actually, I think it should fetch localhost:3333/admin/api. **Is there any way I redirect this request to admin/api?**

Comment: Actually, errors related to fonts appear also when visiting Prisma Studio using the usual method (localhost:5555), so it's obviously not about them

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
//app.module.ts
consumer.apply(ProxyMiddleware).forRoutes('/api');
```

No I Prisma Studio runs on /admin